# How to create tar files automatically

Tags: bash

I like to create tar-files to distribute some scripts using bash.

For every script certain configuration-files and libraries (or toolboxes) are needed,

e.g. a script called CheckTool.py needs Checks.ini, CheckToolbox.py and CommontToolbox.py to run, which are stored in specific folders on my harddisk and need to be copied in the same manner on the users harddisk.

I can create a tarfile manually for each script, but i like to have it more simple.

For this i have the idea to define a list of all needed files and their pathes for a specific script and read this in a bashscript, which creates the tar file.

I started with:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line 
do 
   echo "$line" 

done < $1
```

Which is reading the files and pathes. In my example the lines are:

./CheckTools/CheckMesh.bs

./Configs/CheckMesh.ini

./Toolboxes/CommonToolbox.bs

./Toolboxes/CheckToolbox.bs

My question is how do I have to organize the data to make a tar file with the specified files using bash?
Or is there someone having a better idea?

Comment: Write another shell script (or some `Makefile` target) to make that `tar` file. Use some version control like [git](http://git-scm.com/). It provides some `git archive` command

Comment: Consider also making some package (e.g. a [`.deb` file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_(file_format)) or an [`.rpm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpm_(software)) one) for some [package manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager).

Comment: What do you mean with: write another shell script?

Comment: Use a good [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) to write *another* script which you would run to create the relevant `tar` file. You don't need to "organize data", you need to implement some *archiving and backup procedure*, and shell scripts are good ways to get repeatable and automatable procedures. I am surprised that you asking that! If you prefer to write your script in Python, feel free to do so!

Comment: BTW, it looks like you are reinventing your own package manager. Read also about [shar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a complicated script, use option -T of tar.  Every file listed in there will be added to the tar file:

> -T, --files-from FILE
>              get names to extract or create from FILE

So your script becomes:

```
#!/bin/bash
tar -cvpf something.tar -T listoffiles.txt
```

listoffiles.txt format is super easy, one file per line.  You might want to put full path to ensure you get the right files:

> ./CheckTools/CheckMesh.bs
>   ./Configs/CheckMesh.ini
>   ./Toolboxes/CommonToolbox.bs
>   ./Toolboxes/CheckToolbox.bs

You can add tar commands to the script as needed, or you could loop on the list files, from that point on, your imagination is the limit!